# How do I change the display unit without changing the coordinates numbers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, units

(X= 716 562,800911  Y= 3 568 493,622591 "Decimal Degrees")

My problem is that the coordinates are correct but displayed with the wrong unit, it should be meters. When I try to use the classic way to change it (View-> Data Frame Properties... etc.) it changes the coordinates also.

Is there any way I can change only the display unit?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The display units are based on the projection of the dataframe. If you've got the correct coordinates but wrong units that sounds like a projection has been misdefined somewhere. Have you or anyone else tried to change the projection of the data at all? This sounds like someone may have used Define Projection when they just meant to use Project.